# What are the differences between GPS and GLONASS?

Tags: signal-detection, signal-power, information-theory, localization, gps

I'm studying the localization systems, especially the GPS one.  I inquired about other systems and wanted to understand what are the main differences between GPS and GLONASS, why has the first type taken hold more?
I would especially like to understand the differences in data transmission

Comment: *Why has it taken hold more?* it's 8 years older, was the only system of choice you'd have wanted to use in Western nations (where most non-military GNSS systems were designed for) due to political reasons that you should be aware of :) So, as usualy, market penetration is a result of economic / political effects primarily, technical aspects secondarily.

Comment: So is it fair enough to say that GLONASS didn't explode like GPS purely on the political / economic side? On the technical side it shouldn't change that much in fact

Comment: There's _lots_ of compare/contrast articles on GPS vs. GLONASS.  From a user perspective, GLONASS has fewer satellites, and may be more prone to getting shut off for political reasons.  From a geeky technical perspective, GPS and GLONASS use different reference geodesic.  These days, many GNSS systems use a combination of GPS, GLONASS, and Galileo (and perhaps BeiDou, too -- you can check that with a search).  That helps with satellite coverage and accuracy.

Comment: I suggest you _edit your question_ to ask about which specifics you're interested in.  "Why has GPS taken over more" is both a geopolitical question (and outside the scope of this group), and, since there's a lot of multi-mode receivers out there, perhaps has an embedded factual error.

Comment: @TimWescott It does not seem like a question out of context since I asked precisely if there were any differences in transmission between the two types. The political factor has taken over with regard to the first comment made below my question

Comment: @RiccardoBarbo Welcome here and I'm sure someone will be able to help you-- With all due respect, I do agree with Tim; it would really help if you could narrow your question to technical points that confuse you after doing some simple Google searches / researches on your broad question as stated.